# No audio in Safe Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, system-settings, safe-mode

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) Mojave.  I have been using Safe Mode to see if I can find out information about my trackpad. Then I quickly realized that I do not have any audio. In System Preferences under Sound it says No input devices found. Same for Output. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio is disabled during safe mode since not considered essential function.

Safe mode is considered bare bone operation for troubleshooting.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262